# how to get the authorization to restore mongodb database on server

Tags: mongodb, authorization, mongorestore

While restoring my mongodb database on server using this command:

```
mongorestore -h ds023435*** :23445 -d idea
```

(idea is my database name)

it is showing this error:

```
Failed: idea.questions: error reading database: not authorized on idea to execute  
command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start mongod with authentication. If yes, restart mongod without authentication enabled. Use below command, it will work fine.

mongorestore dump

If it doesn't work open new command prompt with administrator access. Then execute the command. It will work.